# String on table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm running an `each` function on a variable called `data` which is the response from a successful AJAX call, and it's a `json` datatype.

Here is how the data looks in the response:

```
Object { id: "88", toDo: "test 4", instructions: " ;TECH;Dippin;Try try try;Hej SSimon!;", … }
```

I want to add it to a table.

However it will only lay all the strings in one long row, and I want them to be displayed in a table correctly.

[image]

```
var html = '';    

$.each(data, function() {
    var re = 
    html = html + "<tr><td>" + this['instructions'].split(/[\s,;,<]+/) + "</td></tr>";
});

$("#todoInstructions").html(html);
```

Any tips or pointers would be nice!

Comment: you need to split the string, get the array, loop through it and create a `<td>` for each item. P.S. That's assuming you want them to be in separate cells within the same row...you told us what layout you _didn't_ want, but beyond saying they should be in a table we don't know exactly how you _do_ want it to be... "correctly" could mean a number of different things. You want them in separate cells on the same row? Or each on a separate row, or maybe something else?

Comment: I want them to be in separate cells, that's why i am using split and also in the loop adding a new tr.

Comment: Add `.join('</td><td>')` after split

Comment: "I want them to be in separate cells, that's why i am using split"...then why are you putting the results of the split all into one cell? See answer below for a simple example which creates multiple cells. As chris p bacon says, there may be cleverer ways to do it but this sets it out in an easily comprehensible way.

Comment: I tought that when i use split and i was trying to split them up, it would add them to their own row in the each loop.

Comment: Rows and cells are not the same thing. Did you look at my answer below? Does it do what you need?

Answer (score 0):

If you want each item to be in a separate cell, then you need to you need to split the string, get the array, loop through it and create a  for each item. Right now you are just creating a single cell and putting all the items into it. Additionally, the "split" basically has no effect, because although the result of splitting is an array, if you put an array directly into the HTML, JS will try and turn it back into a string, which usually just involves listing all the array items one after the other - so you end up back with the the original string.

This code actually places each item from the split array into its own table cell. It also removes the items which were blank and doesn't create a cell for them.

```js
var data = [{
  id: "88",
  toDo: "test 4",
  instructions: " ;TECH;Dippin;Try try try;Hej SSimon!;"
}];

var html = '';

$.each(data, function() {
  html += "<tr>";
  var items = this.instructions.split(/[\s,;,<]+/);
  console.log(items);
  
  for (item in items) {
    if (items[item] != "")
      html += "<td>" + items[item] + "</td>";
  }
  html += "</tr>";
});

$("#todoInstructions").html(html);
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td,
th {
  border: solid 1px #cccccc;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="todoInstructions"></table>
```

Comment: @chrispbacon feel free to add an answer. Although I think it will leave the blank items in (at least the last one anyway) which is probably undesirable. I wanted to give a super-clear super-simple example showing the logic required as compared to the original, because I think OP is probably struggling with the basic idea here - they didn't seem to see that they'd put everything into one cell.